# Methods to programmatically install a .NET assembly into the GAC

Tags: .net, installation, gac, global-assembly-cache

I need to create a small app or script to install a .NET assembly into the GAC.  I've read there are a couple ways to do this including:

- using `gacutil.exe`
- executing the following line of code:

  `new System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish().GACInstall("Foo.dll");`

However, what would happen if I just created the appropriate directories on the machine and copied the assembly into that directory?  The structure of the GAC directory is the following:  `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Foo\<version#>__<public token>\Foo.dll`

Do the above two methods do anything special besides creating the folder structure and placing the assembly into it?

Comment: Before you experiment, make a backup.

Comment: Revisiting this task recently, I abandoned the app/script idea for an MSI file instead.  Nice and clean!

Comment: Use `GacInstall("Foo.dll")` instead `GACInstall("Foo.dll")`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I *strongly* recommend using existing methods (like the ones you mentioned) because they are both supported and maintained by Microsoft and will continue to work with future releases.

A quick look at `gacutil.exe` with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) reveals that there is a little bit more to it than just copying files:

- concurrency concerns (e.g. temporary files, locking `WINDOWS\assembly\GACLock.dat`, etc.)
- notifications (e.g. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion\GACChangeNotification\...`)
- indexing (e.g. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion\NativeImagesIndex...`)
- validation (e.g. strong name, ...)

The wrapper in `System.EnterpriseServices` is very similar to [this old blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/junfeng/articles/229649.aspx) and should work just fine.

Answer (score 5):

We recently had to do this for 10s of servers in an enterprise environment. We used Wix to build a very simple MSI (seriously - 5 minutes work) and published to all server (and dev boxes) through Group Policy.

Comment: Similar to what we did; we used Visual Studio to build the .msi installation project.

Comment: Thanks.  Ended up using the MSI approach.