# How do I deploy dlls to a system's GAC and check for their existence on program startup?

Tags: entity-framework, gac

Entity Framework references some DLLs.
On one system, they showed up in the GAC which is very convenient.
I can't figure out how I did this. The installer doesn't seem to do this --

The dlls I'm specifically talking about here are:

- The core library assembly Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll
- The Unity Application Block assembly Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll
- The Object Builder assembly Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.dll

but I guess it applies to any dll one might want to add to the GAC.
Also is there a way to check on program startup whether an assembly even is in the GAC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if is in the GAC:

```
bool inGac = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(assemblyName).GlobalAssemblyGac;
```

To install in gac, there's a question
[Methods to programmatically install a .NET assembly into the GAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460793/methods-to-programmatically-install-a-net-assembly-into-the-gac)

Comment: You probably mean the GlobalAssemblyCache property - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.globalassemblycache(v=vs.110).aspx