# Registry Value for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion\GACChangeNotification\Default

Tags: registry, gac

I was studying GAC recently, and I found the GAC assemblies can found in windows registry, see [How can i get the location of the GAC using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557141/how-can-i-get-the-location-of-the-gac-using-c/9887427#9887427).
by C# code, I can get a byte[8] array from any registry item under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion\GACChangeNotification\Default
```

For example:

```
name : System,2.0.0.0,,b77a5c561934e089,MSIL
value in c# code : byte[72,212,154,147,251,33,206,1]
```

And I search in Google, can not find any document for this value, does anybody who knows how to utilize this value?

Comment: GACUTIL.EXE apparently uses it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460793/methods-to-programmatically-install-a-net-assembly-into-the-gac.  I'm wondering why you need to know.  Just curiosity?  Perhaps if you told us the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Yes, just curiosity. In fact, seems we can combine the full assembly string information, which can be used by Assembly.Load, from the key.